# Angular description of @Input / @Output property

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to describe my @Input() and @Output() property in my component, that I see it in the HTML.

for example.

```
   /**
   * Columndefinition of the right grid.
   */
  @Input()
  rightColumnDef?: ColumnDefinition[] = [
    {
      ...
    }
  ];
```

Now I want to see this in the tooltip of my IDE

```
<component
        [rightColumnDef]="columnDef"
></component
```

Please help me how can I do this.

t.

Comment: It depends on your IDE, not on your code. For VSCode for instance, you have to install Angular language service.

Comment: Please add in the tags which IDE you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [Angular Language Service](https://angular.io/guide/language-service). There is documentation how to install it for popular IDE's. Be very attentive, the tool is system resources demanding.